Text file listed in MANIFEST.in disappears when installing python script
I have coded a small CLI tool that I want to be installable. For that I've created a requirements.txt to list the dependencies, a setup.py that is used to install my tool via pip install ..
My tool needs to access a .txt file that I listed in the mainfest.in file. After I've installed the tool because the binary is moved to another path it cannot find the .txt file anymore. How do I fix that?
My setup.py:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

def load_requirements(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        return [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]

setup(
    name='tool',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=load_requirements('requirements.txt'),
    include_package_data=True,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'tool = tool:main',
        ],
    },
)


